# Where can I find english translations of the mythology of the Mnong people?

Tags: translation

The Mnong are one of the many Degar peoples of central Vietnam. They have a series of epic song stories that tell of their mythology.

I have been looking for translations of these. Does anyone know where I can find these? There are Vietnamese versions but unfortunately, I cannot read Vietnamese.

Thanks in advance.

As requested: https://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/005237589

Comment: Can you include a link in your question to the Vietnamese articles?